# Как называются поля для входа в роутер?

Tags: php, jquery, curl, роутер

Нужно узнать `name` полей `<input>` для входа в роутер.

Хочу попробовать брутить через `php` и `jquery` скрипт с помощю `curl`. Может вы посоветуете какойто другой способ.

P.S. Возможности сделать это через ПК - нет. Поэтому нужно через смартфон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Зайди на страницу авторизации роутера;
2. Открой код страницы;
3. Найди необходимые `input`'ы и посмотри параметры `name`.

Comment: Спасибо. Чесно говоря сначала не знал как это сделать но потом нашёл отличную программу для андроид, называется VT Viev Source.